# Proper way of structuring classes?

Tags: coding-style, standards, class-structure

I have a class `Bank`. A bank has a `name`, a list of `Account`s.

I have two banks, bank `A` and `B`. Accounts at bank `A` are slightly different from accounts at bank `B` and my question is basically how would one go about implementing such a structure?

I had a method `Bank.createNewAccount(...)` that creates an `Account`, adds it to the list, and returns it. This worked when `Account` for bank `A` was the same as bank `B`, but now that these differ (`AccountA` and `AccountB` respectively) I don't really know what to do.

Should I create two separate `Bank` classes just to accomodate for their different accounts? Then the implementations of the classes `BankA` and `BankB` would be identical just their Account classes would be different, or is there a simpler approach?

I think it is a language independent question, but just in case, I am writing in Javascript.

Hopefully this is a clear problem statement, but please allow me to edit based on your answers. If needed I can also give a simple mock-up of the code.

Comment: You should make the `Account` "class" a parameter of the `Bank` constructor or the `createNewAccount` function. I.e. it would be like `var bankA = new Bank(AccountA); var bankB = new Bank(AccountB);`. Read up about *dependency-injection*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection. Of course if you have a different account type of each bank then your overall structure might not be ideal.

Comment: I see. If I move some methods that I currently define on the `Account` (like `sendFunds`) to be methods of the `Bank`, then it makes sense to have different `Bank` classes that all use the same `Account`. I think that was my error. Will keep dependency-injection in mind for another time. Thanks! (btw, I can't mark a comment as accepted answer!)